# How to set the maximum height of CSS images?

Tags: html, css

How can I fix the `height` of this image here in this page :

The original size of the image is `196 x 196 px`. But, when the image is loaded on the page, it is shown much bigger than this size.

How this image `height` can be set to maximum `280px`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the image is taking the dimensions of the container.

Use `max-height`

```
.advance-link img {
    max-height: 280px;
    width: auto;
}
```

See the snapshot of the edited properties on your site.

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add a limit to the height. Just add a custom class to the img tag like this:

```
<img class="someName" src="file path" />
```

And then add this to your css:

```
img.someName {
    max-height: 280px;
}
```

Comment: Tushar's answer will edit the height of every other image too whereas, using my custom class method, you can specify which images to add the height limit to.